# How to print a string as an input for a stdin stream?

Tags: python, c, linux, gdb, sh

How can I pass a stdin stream a custom string using for example python with printf? I can't do it before starting the executable because it's something i need to do after some other inputs.

The code is :

```c
void play(){
    int guess=0;
    char buf[CHOICEBUFSIZE];
    long long int attempt=0;
    time_t timer;
    int value;

    time(&timer);
    timer /= 60;
    timer *= 60;

    //printf("<<<<<< Time: %t\n", timer);

    srand(timer);

    do {
        attempt += 1;
        value = rand();
        puts(" > Gimme the magic number or 0 to gtfo!");
        printf(" < ");

        //RIGHT DOWN HERE 
        fgets(buf, CHOICEBUFSIZE, stdin);
        guess = atoi(buf);

    printf("%d\n", value);
        if (guess == value){
            win(attempt);
            return;
        }
        else {
            puts(" > Not even close!\n > Try again!");
        }
    } while (guess);

}
```

Here's a screen showing where I need to input it.

[image]

Thanks in advance. I'm sure the answer is simple but I couldn't find anything similiar to my case.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question. What are you *actually* trying to achieve? See also  http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: This is a computer security exercise, what I'm really trying to do is inject a string to get a buffer overflow. Problem is that this scenario (stdin with fgets) doesn't allow me to achieve it. I can post also the remaining code but even if this looks like a Y problem, it's really just the real problem since it's all about that. But again, if more information may help you find a better solution I can't disagree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stdin is an input stream, so you cannot write to it. Since it sounds like you're trying to perform two tasks in parallel and have one communicate with the other, you may want to look into using pthreads or `fork()`.